# Knockout Doesn't work on Fiddle

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jsfiddle

The following code does not work on jsFiddle even when have set the correct Framework and extension, i.e. jquery 1.7.2 and no-wrap in body.

```
HTML Code    
Name:<input data-bind="value: name" />
<p>Hello, <span data-bind="text: name"></span></p>
<button data-bind="click: changeName">Change Name</button>

Javascript Code   
$(function () {
    var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable("bob"),
        changeName: function () {
            this.name("steve");
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

Comment: I suggest you to share your Jsfiddle, or even better, show your code running here in a Stack Overflow Code Snippet: http://i.imgur.com/ga5xYYD.png

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I'm pretty new at this and especially Javascript. Thanks for at least pointing out improvement needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included jQuery as well as KnockoutJS library while creating your JSFiddle. One of them will be in external resources section on left sidebar because JSFiddle does not provide feature to include both at one go in frameworks and extensions section..

http://jsfiddle.net/yLcqd06q/1/

```
 $(function(){
    var viewModel = {
            name: ko.observable("bob"),
            changeName: function () {
                this.name("steve");
            }
        };
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    });
```

Tip for you : Always mention the error you get in console while posting such questions :-)

Hope that helps..

Peace, RP

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was referring to the pluralsight tutorial and followed everything step by step. The steps clearly spell out that I should only include JQuery framework and never mentioned anything about Knockoutjs. I found that the issue was that I should include knockoutjs instead of JQuery per what the tutorial says.

Comment: @Casperonian Glad you appreciated the effort mate. But you don't have to be rude.. People get pissed off and downvote answer rather than helping the new ones out. Never be like them :-)